# Qt5 C++: Remove item from QListView's model and how to count items

Tags: c++, qt, model, qlistview, qfilesystemmodel

1.
I'm trying to remove one of a few listed files from a QListView model. I'm using this code but it doesn't work:

```
ui->listView->model()->removeRow(ui->viewFiles->currentIndex().row());
```

Same thing is if I use:

```
model->removeRow(ui->viewFiles->currentIndex().row());
```

What's wrong with this code, and how do I delete an item from the list?

2.
  `QFileSystemModel` loads only files from the selected directory. How do I count all those items from `QListView`'s model?

Comment: How is `viewFiles` related to `listView`?

Comment: viewFiles = listView. I was just trying some commands found here on SO, but they weren't working and consequently I forgot to change names back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `removeRow(int row)` should normally works. Make sure that `ui->viewFiles->currentIndex().row()` returns a valid row (i.e., between 0 and `model->rowCount()-1`). Notably, it is possible that your QModelIndex `ui->viewFiles->currentIndex()` is in an invalid state. You can check it via `ui->viewFiles->currentIndex().isValid()`.
2. As said, you can check the number of rows of your model via `model->rowCount()`

Comment: I had to use QDir and QStringListModel, so this works well now.